# How to index multiple values in place of a single value, but maintain shape as though it was a single value?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a problem for which I cannot find a solution regarding some Numpy code I'm writing.  To give some background, I want to implement latency in a neural network.  The neural network has an input array `x` which has a size `[time, trials, neurons]`, and I'd like to assign a certain temporal latency for each neuron.

The simplest case is where there is no latency, and I can feed my network input information like so:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    """ Dummy function so that the code runs """
    return np.mean(x)

# Set up initial state
time, trials, neurons = (100, 256, 16)
x = np.random.rand(time, trials, neurons)

# Iterate through time
for t in range(time):

    # Index into the state in time
    x_ = x[t,:,:]
    y = f(x_)

# Assert shape of indexed array
assert x_.shape == (trials, neurons)
```

In this case, when I index into a particular time, the shape of the array `x` becomes `[trials, neurons]` since I've indexed to a particular time point.

Now, I know I can add a fixed latency `L`, an integer, by indexing with `x[t-L,:,:]`, and the resulting shape is again `[trials, neurons]`.  The result is basically identical to the above code.

To make things tricky, regretfully, my project calls for a different latency for each neuron.  So, instead of having `L` be some integer, I'd like it to be an array of latency values.  Specifically, I'd like to make `L = np.random.randint(a, b, size=neurons)`, so each element of L is some integer between `a` and `b`, exclusive.

My goal is to have an idiomatic code phrase that performs the same way as the integer `L` case.  I know that I can easily do a `for` loop over neurons to achieve an inefficient version of this, as shown:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    """ Dummy function so that the code runs """
    return np.mean(x)

# Set up initial state
time, trials, neurons = (100, 256, 16)
a, b = (8, 12)

x = np.random.rand(time, trials, neurons)
L = np.random.randint(a, b, size=neurons)

# Iterate through time
for t in range(time):

    ### This is what I want to optimize ###
    #######################################

    # Index into the state in time, with
    # a different latency for each neuron
    x_ = []
    for n in range(neurons):
        x_.append(x[t-L[n],:,n])
    x_ = np.stack(x_, axis=1)

    #######################################

    # Use the latency-indexed array
    y = f(x_)

# Assert shape of indexed array
assert x_.shape == (trials, neurons)
```

Thus, my question is how to achieve all of this indexing finagling with hopefully just a few lines of a Numpy-native solution.  I've tried abusing advanced indexing in this regard, but to no avail, and I'm hoping for some help on this matter.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need basic indexing:

```py
import numpy as np

time, trials, neurons = (100, 256, 16)
a, b = (8, 12)
x = np.random.rand(time, trials, neurons)
L = np.random.randint(a, b, size=neurons)

# let's say the time t=50
x1 = []
for n in range(neurons):
    x1.append(x[50-L[n],:,n])
x1 = np.stack(x1, axis=1)

# use two list to index the intersection, but notice transposing needed.
x2 = x[50-L,:,range(neurons)].T

print(np.all(x1==x2))
```

Comment: Goodness, that works!  And here I was losing my mind over advanced indexing and missing the simple solution.  Thank you!  Do you know why that transpose is necessary?

Comment: @aedificatori Because you are selecting out neurons at the time-dimension. Well actually I didn't bother to think the reason...

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense.  Cheers!